# Magento2 Getting Error while reindexing

Tags: magento2, price, catalog, reindex

I'm getting error while trying to reindex

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:06
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:06
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs, query was: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog_product_flat_1_tmp_indexer` (
  `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity Id' ,
  `attribute_set_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Attribute Set ID' ,
  `type_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL default 'simple' COMMENT 'Type Id' ,
  `bat_capacite` int NULL COMMENT 'bat_capacite column' ,
  `bat_capacite_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'bat_capacite column' ,
  `bat_type` int NULL COMMENT 'bat_type column' ,
  `bat_type_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'bat_type column' ,
  `bss_admin_preview` smallint NULL COMMENT 'bss_admin_preview column' ,
  `con_alarme_batterie_elevee` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_alarme_batterie_elevee' ,
  `con_alarme_batterie_faible` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_alarme_batterie_faible' ,
  `con_arret_batterie_faible` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_arret_batterie_faible' ,
  `con_comutateur_transfer` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_comutateur_transfer' ,
  `con_cosummation_vide` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_cosummation_vide' ,
  `con_cosummation_vide_eco` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_cosummation_vide_eco' ,
  `con_courant_dc` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_courant_dc' ,
  `con_courant_de_charge` int NULL COMMENT 'con_courant_de_charge column' ,
  `con_courant_de_charge_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_courant_de_charge column' ,
  `con_courant_de_charge_demar` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_courant_de_charge_demar' ,
  `con_degre_protection` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_degre_protection' ,
  `con_detection_batterie_chargee` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_detection_batterie_chargee' ,
  `con_efficience_max` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_efficience_max' ,
  `con_entre_ac` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_entre_ac' ,
  `con_frequence` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_frequence' ,
  `con_fusible` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_fusible' ,
  `con_humidite` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_humidite' ,
  `con_interrupteur_on_off` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_interrupteur_on_off' ,
  `con_materau_couleur` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_materau_couleur' ,
  `con_mode_stockage` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_mode_stockage' ,
  `con_page_tension` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_page_tension' ,
  `con_parallele_triphase` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_parallele_triphase' ,
  `con_prise_ac` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_prise_ac' ,
  `con_prise_usb` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_prise_usb' ,
  `con_protection` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_protection' ,
  `con_puissance` int NULL COMMENT 'con_puissance column' ,
  `con_puissance_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_puissance column' ,
  `con_puissance_40` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_puissance_40' ,
  `con_puissance_60` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_puissance_60' ,
  `con_puissance_crete` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_puissance_crete' ,
  `con_raccordement_bat` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_raccordement_bat' ,
  `con_redemar_batterie_faible` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_redemar_batterie_faible' ,
  `con_relais_programmable` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_relais_programmable' ,
  `con_section_cable` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_section_cable' ,
  `con_temp_fonctionnement` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_temp_fonctionnement' ,
  `con_temp_trop_elevee` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_temp_trop_elevee' ,
  `con_tension_ac` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_tension_ac' ,
  `con_tension_charge_absorption` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_tension_charge_absorption' ,
  `con_tension_charge_float` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_tension_charge_float' ,
  `con_type` int NULL COMMENT 'con_type column' ,
  `con_type_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_type column' ,
  `con_type_batteries` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_type_batteries' ,
  `con_ve_bus_port` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'con_ve_bus_port' ,
  `cost` decimal(12,4) NULL COMMENT 'cost' ,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'created_at' ,
  `description` longtext NULL COMMENT 'description' ,
  `disponibility` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'disponibility column' ,
  `ge_demarage` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ge_demarage column' ,
  `ge_phase` int NULL COMMENT 'ge_phase column' ,
  `ge_phase_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ge_phase column' ,
  `ge_puissance_max` int NULL COMMENT 'ge_puissance_max column' ,
  `ge_puissance_max_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ge_puissance_max column' ,
  `ge_type` int NULL COMMENT 'ge_type column' ,
  `ge_type_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ge_type column' ,
  `gift_message_available` smallint NULL COMMENT 'gift_message_available column' ,
  `has_options` smallint NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'has_options' ,
  `icon_type` int NULL COMMENT 'icon_type column' ,
  `icon_type_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'icon_type column' ,
  `image` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'image' ,
  `image_label` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'image_label' ,
  `is_freedelivery` smallint NULL COMMENT 'is_freedelivery column' ,
  `links_exist` int NULL COMMENT 'links_exist' ,
  `links_purchased_separately` int NULL COMMENT 'links_purchased_separately' ,
  `links_title` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'links_title' ,
  `manufacturer` int NULL COMMENT 'manufacturer column' ,
  `manufacturer_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'manufacturer column' ,
  `msrp` decimal(12,4) NULL COMMENT 'msrp' ,
  `msrp_display_actual_price_type` text NULL COMMENT 'msrp_display_actual_price_type' ,
  `name` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'name' ,
  `news_from_date` datetime NULL COMMENT 'news_from_date' ,
  `news_to_date` datetime NULL COMMENT 'news_to_date' ,
  `ond_ac_courant_max` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_ac_courant_max' ,
  `ond_courant_charge_max` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_courant_charge_max' ,
  `ond_courant_decharge_max` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_courant_decharge_max' ,
  `ond_eps_courant_nominal` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_eps_courant_nominal' ,
  `ond_eps_delai_de_communication` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_eps_delai_de_communication' ,
  `ond_eps_frequence` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_eps_frequence' ,
  `ond_eps_puissance_crete` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_eps_puissance_crete' ,
  `ond_eps_puissance_nom` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_eps_puissance_nom' ,
  `ond_eps_tension_nominal` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_eps_tension_nominal' ,
  `ond_eps_thd` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_eps_thd' ,
  `ond_fonct_parallele` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_fonct_parallele' ,
  `ond_phases` int NULL COMMENT 'ond_phases column' ,
  `ond_phases_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_phases column' ,
  `ond_plage_de_frequences` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_plage_de_frequences' ,
  `ond_plage_de_tension_mpp` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_plage_de_tension_mpp' ,
  `ond_plage_tension` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_plage_tension' ,
  `ond_protect_surcharge` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_protect_surcharge' ,
  `ond_puissance_pv_max` int NULL COMMENT 'ond_puissance_pv_max column' ,
  `ond_puissance_pv_max_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_puissance_pv_max column' ,
  `ond_puissance_sortie_ac` int NULL COMMENT 'ond_puissance_sortie_ac column' ,
  `ond_puissance_sortie_ac_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_puissance_sortie_ac column' ,
  `ond_pv_courant_max` int NULL COMMENT 'ond_pv_courant_max column' ,
  `ond_pv_courant_max_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_pv_courant_max column' ,
  `ond_tension_batterie` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_tension_batterie' ,
  `ond_tension_entre` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_tension_entre' ,
  `ond_tension_entre_ac` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_tension_entre_ac' ,
  `ond_tension_entre_min` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_tension_entre_min' ,
  `ond_topologie` int NULL COMMENT 'ond_topologie column' ,
  `ond_topologie_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_topologie column' ,
  `ond_type` int NULL COMMENT 'ond_type column' ,
  `ond_type_value` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_type column' ,
  `ond_type_batterie` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'ond_type_batterie' ,
  `panel_type` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'panel_type column' ,
  `price` decimal(12,4) NULL COMMENT 'price' ,
  `price_type` int NULL COMMENT 'price_type' ,
  `price_view` int NULL COMMENT 'Bundle Price View price_view column' ,
  `required_options` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'required_options' ,
  `short_description` longtext NULL COMMENT 'short_description' ,
  `sku` varchar(64) NULL COMMENT 'sku' ,
  `sku_type` int NULL COMMENT 'sku_type' ,
  `small_image` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'small_image' ,
  `small_image_label` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'small_image_label' ,
  `special_from_date` datetime NULL COMMENT 'special_from_date' ,
  `special_price` decimal(12,4) NULL COMMENT 'special_price' ,
  `special_to_date` datetime NULL COMMENT 'special_to_date' ,
  `swatch_image` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'swatch_image' ,
  `tax_class_id` int UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'tax_class_id tax column' ,
  `thumbnail` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'thumbnail' ,
  `thumbnail_label` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'thumbnail_label' ,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL COMMENT 'updated_at' ,
  `url_key` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'url_key' ,
  `url_path` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'url_path' ,
  `visibility` smallint UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'Catalog Product Visibility visibility column' ,
  `weight` decimal(12,4) NULL COMMENT 'weight' ,
  `weight_type` int NULL COMMENT 'weight_type' ,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`entity_id`),
  INDEX `CATALOG_PRODUCT_FLAT_1_TMP_INDEXER_TYPE_ID` (`type_id`),
  INDEX `CATALOG_PRODUCT_FLAT_1_TMP_INDEXER_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID` (`attribute_set_id`),
  INDEX `CATALOG_PRODUCT_FLAT_1_TMP_INDEXER_NAME` (`name`),
  INDEX `CATALOG_PRODUCT_FLAT_1_TMP_INDEXER_OND_TENSION_ENTRE` (`ond_tension_entre`),
  INDEX `CATALOG_PRODUCT_FLAT_1_TMP_INDEXER_PRICE` (`price`)
) COMMENT='Catalog Product Flat (Store 1)' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
Category Flat Data index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:14
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:05
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:23
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some column from `VARCHAR` to `TEXT or BLOBs`.

You are getting that message because the sum of all the fields is > 65k.
Even you can set `TEXT(255)`. you can learn more from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-count-limit.html).

Comment: Yes, `You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs` that is mention in error but how can i do that? I have to alter table structure for this table? or table creating dynamically when i run this command? dont know

Comment: I would suggest you update your custom attributes from  `VARCHAR` to `TEXT or BLOBs`. Magento will dynamically set them to  `TEXT or BLOBs`

Comment: It's dropdown How can i change now and it's too many

Comment: Or should i change structure of this table 'catalog_product_flat_1_tmp_indexer'?If my changes to this table will not rollback after my next reindexing process

Comment: Yes, it will not rollback but you will have to update them while re-index. That all attributes are drop down?

Comment: I cant find that table in database,most of attributes are dropdown

Comment: yes, because of row size limit issue.

Comment: So,how can I avoid it,which table structure should I change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78013/discussion-between-kunj-and-ketan).